# Is there a homomorphism from a full product of finite cyclic groups onto $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, abstract-algebra

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051338/maps-to-all-finite-cyclic-groups-factor-implies-map-to-integers-factors), I encountered the following question, the answer to which should be known but it is hard to Google, so I did not find it.

Let $G=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z_n$ be a *full* product of finite cyclic groups $\mathbb Z_n=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Exists there a homomorphism $f:G\to\mathbb Z$ such that $f((1,1,\dots))=1$?

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363012/abelian-group-admitting-a-surjective-homomorphism-onto-an-infinite-cyclic-group?rq=1), my question should be equivalent to the following.

Is the group $\{(m,m,\dots)\in G: m\in\mathbb Z\}$ a direct summand of the group $G$?

Comment: Interesting question!  Just a thought: by composing with the projection $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}} \mathbb{Z} \to \prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ we can instead ask if there is a homomorphism $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with the above properties.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ include $0$?
$\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z} = \{0\}$. Or does it start at $2$?

Comment: @SpamIAm A homomorphism from $f:\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ such that $f((1,1,\dots))=1$ exists - it is a projection to 1st coordinate.

Comment: @Krahapp No, $\mathbb N$ does not include $0$. The factor $\mathbb Z_1$ can be skipped.

Comment: Hm, but that homomorphism doesn't descend to the quotient.  I guess we also need to have $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}} n \mathbb{Z}$ contained in the kernel of the homomorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only homomorphisms $\varphi:\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ are the obvious ones
$$\varphi\left(a_1,a_2,\dots\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_nb_n,$$ 
where $\left(b_1,b_2,\dots\right)$ is a sequence of integers with $b_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. In particular, $\varphi$ is determined by its restriction to $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$. For a proof, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-ring-ove/10249#10249.

But the obvious map $\theta:\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \to \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ sends every element of $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$ to a torsion element, which must therefore be in the kernel of any homomorphism  $\alpha:\prod_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. So by the theorem above, $\alpha\circ\theta=0$ and so $\alpha=0$.