# Given surjective Homomorphism $f:A \to B$ then $A \cong \ker(f) × B$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

Given surjective Homomorphism $f:A \to B$ when $B$ is a free abelian group.

> Prove: $A \cong \ker(f) × B$

I have seen this claim in the following link:

[Abelian group admitting a surjective homomorphism onto an infinite cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363012/abelian-group-admitting-a-surjective-homomorphism-onto-an-infinite-cyclic-group/363020#363020)

But couldn't find any proof online. I have tried to prove it using the following claim but I don't think the same claim works for general $\mathbb{Z}^n$
https://yutsumura.com/surjective-group-homomorphism-to-z-and-direct-product-of-abelian-groups/

Please note that I haven't learned exact sequences yet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let $\{b_i : i \in I\}$ be a free basis of $B$. For each $i \in I$ choose $a_i \in A$ with $f(a_i) = b_i$, and let $C$ be the subgroup of $A$ generated by the $a_i$. Prove that $C \cong B$ and $A = \ker f \times C$.

Comment: @Derek Holt This is exactly what I was trying to do. How ever I can't see why $C \cong B$?

Comment: Clearly $f(C) = B$, and so $B \cong C/(C \cap \ker f)$. So you need to prove that $C \cap \ker f = \{0\}$. This is where you use the fact that $B$ is free abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you say that you didn't learn [exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) yet, but what exactly stops you from doing that? This tool is not difficult at all and reduces lots of boilerplate.

So you have a short exact sequence of abelian groups:

$$0\to \ker(f)\to A\xrightarrow{f} B\to 0$$

with $B$ free abelian. Let $\{b_i\}$ be a basis of $B$. For each $i$ choose $a_i\in A$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$ and define $g:B\to A$ by $g(b_i)=a_i$. Since $B$ is free abelian then $g$ is a well defined homomorphism. With that you can easily check that the sequence splits and so we can apply [the splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) to conclude that $A\simeq\ker(f)\times B$.

---

**Side note.** This is a special case of the more general fact that if $R$ is a ring then a $R$-module $P$ is projective if and only if every sequence of the form

$$0\to A\to B\to P\to 0$$

splits. It just happens that the category of abelian groups is the same as the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and projective modules coincide with free abelian groups.