# Let $f:\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a surjective homomorphism. Prove or disprove $\mathbb{Z}^2\cong\mathbb{Z}\times \ker(f)$

Tags: group-theory

I feel like Im overlooking some simple fact on this one, so any hints would be appreciated.

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551119/given-surjective-homomorphism-fa-to-b-then-a-cong-kerf-%C3%97-b) solution, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it without short exact sequences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you proven that subgroups of free abelian groups are free and that free abelian groups have well defined ranks?

Comment: I haven't.

We did some stuff with finitely generated abelian groups, but nothing with free abelian groups.

Comment: If this makes sense to you: a short exact sequence $0\to A \to B \to C \to 0$ splits if $C$ is free, in that case $B\cong A\oplus C$ (I think direct sum is more appropriate here, though the difference doesn't matter for these groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple enough to be proved explicitly.

We pick any $v \in \Bbb Z^2$ such that $f(v) = 1$ and we define a homomorphism $h:\Bbb Z \times \ker(f) \rightarrow \Bbb Z^2$ by $h(a, x) = av + x$.

$h$ is surjective: if $y$ is any vector in $\Bbb Z^2$, then $h(f(y), y - f(y)v) = y$.

$h$ is injective: if $h(a, x) = 0$, then we have $av + x = 0$ and applying $f$ gives $a = 0$, which then implies $x = 0$.

Comment: Interesting.

Can you share what kinds of considerations you had at the front of your mind when you came up with this answer? Did it "just occur" to you, or is there some crucial set of ideas that this question primed you to think about which made your solution come to you?

Comment: In fact, I just translated the answer using short exact sequences (see comment of @JustinYoung above) to this explicit version. This might be a motivation for you to learn the more abstract method.

Comment: That's definitely motivation for me to learn the more abstract method. Thanks for sharing your thoughts.